# Zend Framework view script, functions and variable scope

Tags: php, zend-framework, fatal-error

I am rather new to ZendFramework and am trying to figure this out. In my view script (index.phtml), I have this bit of code that says:

```
<?php

function getErrorString($element)
{
echo "<pre>";
print_r($this);
echo "</pre>";

 $string = '';
 if(!empty($this->error[$element]))
 {
  $string = $string.'<label class="error" for="'.$element.'" generated="true">';
  foreach($this->error[$element] as $error)
  {
   $string = $string.$error; 
  }
  $string = $string.'</label>';
 }
 return $string;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($this);
echo "</pre>";
getErrorString("blah");
die();
```

That gives me:

```
 Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in index.phtml on line XX
```

It seems to me that when you create a function within a view, you lose the $this variable. I did search around the net, and I can't see anyone else trying to achieve what I am doing (highly unlikely, maybe I'm searching it wrong).

With past experience developing other apps, I can't see a good reason why this function should be placed in a separate helper -> especially since this is the only place the function will ever be called.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function getErrorString() isn't an objectmethod of the Zend_View-Object.
It has it's own scope and couldn't reach $this.

The following code should work for you in the index.phtml

```
function getErrorString($viewObject, $element)
{
echo "<pre>";
print_r($viewObject);
echo "</pre>";

 $string = '';
 if(!empty($viewObject->error[$element]))
 {
  $string = $string.'<label class="error" for="'.$element.'" generated="true">';
  foreach($viewObject->error[$element] as $error)
  {
   $string = $string.$error; 
  }
  $string = $string.'</label>';
 }
 return $string;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($this);
echo "</pre>";
getErrorString($this,"blah");
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

The last use of "`$this`" variable is probably the main reason for showing the fatal error. It's quite justified because of the fact that you cannot write anything else in the class definition, **except defining methods & properties with respect to that class**.

Also if you are creating any function in a view page, then within that function the "`$this`" variable is not accessible by default. So you will have to make that "`$this`" variable go global or you need to print the required part, related to "$this" variable, outside the function definition.

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($this);
echo "</pre>";
```

So when you are writing the above code in the function definition, the PHP Parser is unable to find any object context for this "`$this`" variable. It's not that you are losing that "$this" variable, but it will not be accessible, but to the missing logic.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response KC!

I am not sure if I understand what you mean though. You said you cannot write anything else in the class definition, but then said that you are allowed to define methods?

Also, I don't see why it'll print_$(this) would work, but getErrorString("blah") would not.

Cheers!

Comment: @lyf - Since your function definition is not binded within a class definition, so the use of "$this" within the function definition will not work.